# API getting username and password with exact target

Tags: soap-api, php, marketing-cloud

My code snippet

```
 require('exacttarget_soap_client.php');

    $wsdl = 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl';

    try {
          @$client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));
          $client->username = '*****';
          $client->password = '******';
          $param = new ExactTarget_VersionInfoRequestMsg();
          $param->IncludeVersionHistory = True;
          $results = $client->VersionInfo($param);
          var_dump($results);     
    }catch (SoapFault $e) {
          var_dump($e);
    }
```

Its getting the error:

```
["message":protected]=>
string(19) "User not authorized"
["string":"Exception":private]=>
string(0) ""
["code":protected]=>
```

I am able to login https://***.exacttarget.com/hub/ using these credential. Its wroking fine. But when I am using API Code it give the above error.

Answer (score 1):

In general - here is a list of SOAP error's you will see with ExactTarget - http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/soap_faults/

In the IMH you'll want to follow this path:

1.In the top right of your screen hover over the "Welcome ..." and you'll see this drop down.

[image: In the top right of your screen hover over the "Welcome ..." and you'll see this drop down.]

2. Click on the "User Preferences" pane
3. You'll see an overlay / modal come up, then click on the "Edit" button in that modal.
4. You will then see a screen like the following
   [image: You will then see a screen like the following]

Comment: Posting answer here as the questions section on Code@ will eventually be removed.

Comment: Make sure to mark questions as answered as well, so that others know they are completed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do NOT have API and WebService permissions enabled for your user. This [link](https://code.exacttarget.com/question/api-create-subscriber-error-user-not-authorized) provides more details on how/ where you can fix this setting.